# Android Cold Start Analytics

Tags: android, continuous-integration

I am looking for the best way to determine cold-start time of my Android application.

These statistics are available through various blogs on the more popular apps, and it's something I would be interested in monitoring in my own app development.

Ideally, I'd like to add it to my Continuous Integration running on Jenkins.